# Is there a way to specify Content-Encoding (e.g. 'gzip' compression) for a subdomain in an Azure Web App?

Tags: azure, unity-game-engine, http, header, compression

I am making WebGL Unity games and hosting them in Azure Web Apps. I have managed to get gzip to work on the root. But the actual JavaScript and build files are at `https://URL.tld/Build/...` and none of the sub-directories have gzip enabled. I am getting warnings in the console that I could serve these files as
gzip to speed up performance.

Now, it seems the games are loading quite fast. And I am curious if I even need gzip enabled for the subdomain at this point.

Upon inspecting the network tab I can see that the calls being made to the build folder indeed are coming back with a response missing the `Content-Encoding: gzip` that I am looking for despite the request having the proper `Accept-Encoding`.

My `web.config` contains:

```xml
<urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true" />
  <httpCompression>
      <dynamicTypes>
          <clear />
          <add enabled="true" mimeType="text/*"/>
          <add enabled="true" mimeType="message/*"/>
          <add enabled="true" mimeType="application/x-javascript"/>
          <add enabled="true" mimeType="application/javascript"/>
          <add enabled="true" mimeType="application/json"/>
          <add enabled="false" mimeType="*/*"/>
          <add enabled="true" mimeType="application/atom+xml"/>
          <add enabled="true" mimeType="application/atom+xml;charset=utf-8"/>
      </dynamicTypes>
      <staticTypes>
          <clear />
          <add enabled="true" mimeType="text/*"/>
          <add enabled="true" mimeType="message/*"/>
          <add enabled="true" mimeType="application/javascript"/>
          <add enabled="true" mimeType="application/atom+xml"/>
          <add enabled="true" mimeType="application/xaml+xml"/>
          <add enabled="true" mimeType="application/json"/>
          <add enabled="false" mimeType="*/*"/>
      </staticTypes>
  </httpCompression>
```

Which is what I assume is allowing the root to work with gzip. Maybe I need to use Front Door or do a rewrite rule?

Comment: Hi @goonstax running to the same issue trying to add brotli, did you figure this out?